# How to set toast as message send and not sent in JavaMail, Android application

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

I want a toast when mail sending is success as "Message Sent",
and when mal sending is unsuccessful then as "Message Not Sent"

How to do it... thanks

```
class RetreiveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("example@gmail.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse(recpient));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setReplyTo(InternetAddress
                    .parse("example@gmail.com"));
            message.setContent(
                    textmessage,
                    "text/html; charset=utf-8");

            Transport.send(message);

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String feed) {
        pdialog.dismiss();
        reciept.setText("");
        msg.setText("");
        sub.setText("");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message sent",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `String` you return in `doInBackground` is the parameter you get in `onPostExecute`.

You could return `null` when everything's work, and `e.getMessage()` if any `Exception` occurs. Then, in `onPostExecute` show the confirmation toast if `feed` is `null`, or the error is isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Handler

```
private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

and a variable `private String message = ""`
And in `doInBackground` change its value accordingly i.e. `message="Mail Sent";` or `message="Mail Not Sent";` and call `handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);` whenever you want to show toast